# UITableViewCell custom IBOutlet connection crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I made a custom view for a tablecell, i have some elements in the cell, i have coded the correct IBOutlet conenctions etc etc.

When I do not make any IBOutlet connections, I get to see the custom cell i made, so the class and reference are all good.

The moment I make a connection to an element, and compile i get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SearchViewController 0x1d05f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'
```

the .h file...
again, without connections it works (but again I cannot modify the elements which is the whole idea of a custom cell) I get this error after connecting to IBOutlet...

I have also tried to connect 1 by 1, but they all give an error in the same range

CustomTableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelHeader;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelDescription;
    IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonPrice;
    IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonSize;
    IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonFloor;
    IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonBeds;
    IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonBaths;
}

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelHeader;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDescription;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonPrice;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonSize;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonFloor;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonBeds;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *labelButtonBaths;

@end
```

CustomTableCell.m

```
#import "CustomTableCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableCell

@synthesize image;
@synthesize labelHeader;
@synthesize labelDescription;
@synthesize labelButtonPrice;
@synthesize labelButtonSize;
@synthesize labelButtonFloor;
@synthesize labelButtonBeds;
@synthesize labelButtonBaths;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

tableview from search table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CustomTableCellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";

    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomTableCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Now, when i make no connecitons at all, i get to see the custom cell,
when i make a connection it stops.

Comment: Have you read the 'reason' itgave?

Comment: I'm surprised that code even compiles (it won't for me). You shouldn't duplicate a property with an ivar - the point of properties is to eliminate ivars (and all the glue code they require) altogether. Simply remove the ivars contained in the {}s and the problem should disappear.

Comment: If while in IB/storyboard editor, you right-click on the image `UIImage`, does it show more than a single Outlet Connection?  If so, delete the unneeded connection(s).

Comment: i'm not using storyboard, and i am not deleting it anywhere.

Comment: it's not giving me a reason either just this error

Comment: 1. I have no idea what you just wrote and 2. I'm sure it's not an answer but a comment? or am i too noobish to understand

Comment: @David having ivars **and** properties is valid, although with current compiler we do not need that indeed. It however does not address original problem - outlet is being connected to the wrong object

Comment: ok good luck with that

Comment: Hmm ... does compile and works fine from a storyboard using a custom accessor / mutator. Is it loaded from an XIB?

Comment: yes loaded from XIB, i'll post code hang on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem can happen when you have your custom cell in a xib file and connect your IBOutlet to "File owner" object, not to cell itself.

Then when you try to load your cell from xib with your view controller as file owner for a xib it tries to connect `image` to non-existing property of controller.

Try to check your outlet connections and make sure they are connected only to your cell, not to any other objects

Comment: how do i connect that? i'm trying to select it, but it keeps going to the files owner

Comment: Have you set your cell in xib file to be your custom class? (select your cell in IB, open utility panel (the one that slides from the right side of screen, go to "identity inspector" - 3rd tab in the panel and make sure your custom class name is in "class" field)

Comment: yes, it points to the CustomTableCell class which is a subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: oh hang on, select the cell and then set the class to CustomTableCell, i selected file owner and set the class to CustomTableCell. What should the file owner class be then?

Comment: What I usually do is set **cell** class to be a custom class and leave file owner class default (NSObject) - as it does not matter when you load the cell. It may depend however on how you load your cell in code.

Comment: yes that's it!!!! When i set the class for file owner to NSObject and the cell to the custom class, then make connecitons it works!!! thanks!

Comment: Saw your code, in your case if all outlet connections will be to cell itself you can even leave fileOwner parameter nil and everything should still work fine. Also check new 'registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:' method in UITableView - it will simplify cell loading code a lot

Comment: I guess the clue was in ***"reason: '[<SearchViewController 0x1d05f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image."***

Comment: @MikePollard, right, error descriptions in console are very useful and first thing everyone should check

Comment: Thanks for Amazing answer,
To connect my image with my cell I've first added IBOutlet code in my custom cell file, then dragged IBOutlet dot from code file to xib file and connected to CustomCell instead of file's owner.